# Simple Objective-C question : why is main a method and not a function?

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a simple Objective-C tutorials for some friends and it came to a very simple question I could not answer. In a Foundation Tool project, why is *main* a method? At least its is called "*main-method*" in all the books I read.

Let me tell you about the details ... I made a small program where a NSMutableArray is sorted with a function. I put the function before *main* and it all works fine.
**My problem is how to explain a beginner why *main* is a method while the code to sort the array is a function.** It's hard to see any difference.

We all know methods always belong to classes while functions do not but in my project I have no classes only the main.m. A C++ guy like me I expected *main* to be *static* but it is not.

So the question is "Why is main a method and not a function?" Or is it not? Or is it something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah.... well you're mixing C and Objective-C syntax I believe.

If, in main.m you've got the following:

```
  void sortArray(NSMutableArray *a)
   {

   }

   int main( const int argc, char** argv )
   {

   }
```

Then I believe the correct terminology is that they're both C-style Function Calls.  They persist in a C manner, not in an object-oriented manner like in C++, C#, or Java.  You can even make C `extern` variables and functions, I think.

BUT

if you call

```
[array addObject:insert];
```

You're calling an Objective-C method (`invoking a message`, technically).  Defined like the following.

```
@interface myClass : NSObject
{
    int myIvar;
}

+ (id) myStaticMethod: (NSObject *)parameter;
- (void) myInstanceMethod: (NSObject *)parameter;

@end

@implementation

+ (id) myStaticMethod: (NSObject *)parameter
{

}

- (void) myInstanceMethod: (NSObject *)parameter
{

}

@end
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

`main` in Objective-C is exactly the same `main` in C or C++. A stand-alone function which is the entry point of the program. Some books may call it the main method because they are a little loose with the terminology.

Technically, Objective-C has methods, which are invoked in response to messages being sent to an object. C++ has member functions, which are called directly.

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference between Function and Method, both are same. Some languages has some terminology. In C, it is called as function, In C++, it is called as member-function, in java, objective-c, it is called as method.

Comment: This is not accurate - generally speaking, methods and functions are not the same, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/155609/369317